# Any way to block a specific HTTPS request from a specific application?

Tags: network, firewall

There's an app running on my mac (macOS 10.12.6) that occasionally makes an HTTPS request to a resource at a specific URL. I'd like to block this request, but allow all other requests from this application to go through, as well as requests from every other application on my system.

Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: I'd look into littlesnitch.app.

Comment: Do you have the specific url you want to block?

Comment: if the URL is unique you can block the domain by pointing it to localhost in the hosts file.